# How to prove this sequent by natural deduction?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

How do I prove

$$\forall x\forall y\forall z(S(x, y)\land S(y, z) \Rightarrow S(x, z)), \forall x\neg S(x, x) \vdash \forall x\forall y(S(x, y) \Rightarrow \neg S(y, x)).$$

by natural deduction?

1 $\quad \forall x\forall y\forall z(S(x, y)\land S(y, z) \Rightarrow S(x, z))\quad \text{premise}$

2 $\quad\forall x\neg S(x, x) \quad\text{premise}$

I don't know what's the next step, replace $x$ by some term?

I got it!!
[image: myAns]

Comment: What did you try?  What rules are you working with? (there are many different proof systems, each with their own set of rules ..)

Comment: by predicate natural deduction

Comment: That is not specific enough ... again, there are many different systems for 'predicate natural deduction' ... can you post those rules?  Or maybe have an online link?

Comment: I just added in the above

Comment: That helps ... how is your $\forall$ Intro defined?  (especially that one is defined differently between different systems ...) Do you have an example for that?

Comment: I've added some example (line 3), but I don't know whether this is correct or not.

Comment: Your first step is wrong.  Your first step should be to come up with any proof at all of the statement, before trying to convert that proof to natural deduction.  You have to have a reason for thinking it is true before you can make a proof.  This is not a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume $S(x,y)$ and $S(y,x)$. Then $S(x,x)$ by the first premise, contradicting the second premise.

Comment: What is assume S(x, y) and S(y, x)? I haven't do the \forall eliminate yet.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

It's always good to think about this informally, and then try to formalize that.  Thinking about it informally will clarify your all-important proof *strategy*.

OK, so you want to prove:

$$\forall x\forall y(S(x, y) \Rightarrow \neg S(y, x))$$

This means that you consider and $x$ and $y$, assume that $S(x,y)$, and then try to show $\neg S(y,x)$.

And for the latter, since it is a negation, probably a proof by contradiction will be good, i.e. assume that you *do* have $S(y,x)$, and show that that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I can understand what you said, but this problem is still too complicated for me. Could you provide some further hint?

Comment: Like I said, don't get too caught up with the symbols and the rules initially: you want to see the forest through the trees!  The fact that you try and solve this problem 1 step at a time tells me that you're not really thinking about a strategy, but it is that strategy that is often key to solving these problems. So, before I provide any further hints, I want you to consider what I said in my post about a high-level proof strategy: can you see how that will work?

Comment: It's still too hard for me.. I don't know how to deal with those \forall correctly.

Comment: @walkcc  You have no example for that?  Are you using a book?

Comment: Yes, there are some examples. But how can I assume S(x, y) and S(y, x) then get contradiction thus get negation of S(y, x). I cannot operate these things without eliminate \forall.

Comment: I don't know "how can I assume S(x, y)."

Comment: @walkcc Without knowing the rules, I don't know either how you can do that in your system ... you really have no examples or a book title or some web link to your system?

Comment: The book is <Logic in Computer Science>

Comment: By Huth and Ryan?

Comment: Yes, it's by Huth and Ryan.

Comment: @walkcc OK, cool. Well, I see that they have the rule for $\forall$ i (Intro) on page 110.  You'll also need to contradiction ($\bot$) rule to derive a contradiction, and the $\neg$ i rule to derive a negation once some assumption leads to a cpontradiction. Finally, you can make assumptions at any point in the proof, as long as you start that inside a new box.  I have to be offline for a while, but look at the rules, think about my strategy, and good luck!

Comment: Thx:) I'll do my best!

Comment: I thought I've got the point! I just updated myAns. Could you check it latter? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @walkcc Eh, yes, that is totally correct .... Did you find this somewhere?  To be really honest ... that's a bit hard to believe you got all that given how lost you were earlier ... Typically students starting with this material take at least a few weeks to get up to speed with these proofs.

Comment: I've learned proposition logic last week, and I just studied the predicate logic now. All these stuff were written by myself honestly.

Comment: @walkcc  OK, well, well done then!!